# Labeled graph representation in Java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, graph

Suppose we have a directed labeled graph, i.e. a graph where the edges from a vertex to another are labeled with a value. How can we model this in Java? (or in an object oriented language in general?)

My current solution is to have a class `Vertex` which has a `Collection<Edge> outgoingEdges` and a `Collection<Edge> incomingEdges`, where `Edge` is a class that has three fields:

- `label` which is the label of the edge
- `predecessor` which is the source `Vertex`
- `successor` which is the destination `Vertex`

Other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say you need to separate out the outgoing and incoming edges, you can just check whether the vertex is the source or target and have a utility method that gives you outgoing and incoming. I notice a lot of implementations code directed and undirected graphs differently, there really is no reason to.

Comment: you're right, even though, in terms of efficiency, distinguishing the vertices can avoid repeating filtering

Comment: Efficiency and OO languages (particularly VMs) don't sit so well together. If raw speed was the target you would use an adjacency matrix (or at least replace objects with some primitive types). I've been writing graph libraries for 9 years now and I would honestly say it comes down to OO abstraction or raw speed, there's rarely a case to justify anything in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK. It's analogous to the standard technique of modelling a many-to-many relationship in a database with an auxillary table to hold info about the relationship.

Do you also have a collection of root vertices?

Depending on what traversals you need to do, you may not need incoming edges - e.g. if you only ever start from the roots.

Strictly speaking you don't even need Vertex objects, if that hasn't got any other information attached, you can just number the vertices and put the numbers in predecessor and successor for each edge. That may be going a bit far, however :)

Comment: ... what do you mean by "root vertex"? As far as I recall, only trees have roots... or not?

I didn't mention that nodes have information in them, so they're needed, but you are right underlining they can be omitted in some cases. The predecessors can be useful in a generic data structure, but you're right, they aren't strictly necessry to represent the structure I described

Comment: By root verticies I meant the collection of vertices that have no predecessors. The starting points for most traversals, probably

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did was right. And you can add a Graph class which have list of vertex and list of edge as the members.

You have represented all the entities as object, so that looks okay to me.